# How to click button from code in UniversalApp?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

**Before downvote**: let me remind that there is no method "btnDoSomething.Click();"

xaml contents:

```
<AppBarButton x:Name="btnDoSomething" Icon="Accept"/>
```

I want to click it from "OnNavigatedTo" method. How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Don't click a button from code in order to do the same action in a different event.

Let `btnDoSomething` execute the same method on click which you can call in `OnNavigatedTo`.

```
    private void appBarButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DoStuff();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        DoStuff();
    }

    private void DoStuff()
    {
        //...
    }
```

Comment: Yea, I know that. Why I can't just raise button click event somehow?

Comment: Obviously Microsoft wants to prevent developers to do bad things like rasing click events in code. 
If you know that you shouldn't do that then why do you still want to do it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to click a button on the OnNavigatedTo!?. When you click a button you wanna ToDO and Code. Do that ToDO and Code in your OnNavigatedTo.

But If you wanna click it just call the method `btnDoSomething_Click(sender, args);`

Comment: the OP is trying to programmatically force a click ON the button, not wire the control up so that it has an onClick event.

Comment: Ok changed it. Sorry:(